# Comparing chars does not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've got 12, 6 in the first word, 6 in the second.

Why this is not working:

```
if 
    (aChar1 == aChar7)
    (aChar2 == aChar8){
        //do something
    }
```

Meaning, if aChar1 is equal to aChar7 and aChar2 is Equal to aChar8 do something, it gives me errors...

Comment: Because that isn't valid C syntax.

Comment: It's not valid anything syntax...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It shouldn't even compile...the correct syntax is

```
if ((aChar1 == aChar7) && (aChar2 == aChar8)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: hope you don't mind me adding some extra brackets :)

Comment: @rokjarc I'll keep your edit, however maybe for such a simple comparison adding brackets may be more confusing than helpful. :)